# "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists." Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I make an autoencoder modeling as below, it occured a "Another metric with the same name already exists" error.

What is the problem?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

nb_epoch = 50
batch_size = 32
input_dim = df_train_0_x_rescaled.shape[1] 
encoding_dim = 32
hidden_dim = int(encoding_dim / 2)
learning_rate = 1e-3

input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(input_dim, ))
encoder = layers.Dense(encoding_dim, activation="relu", activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(learning_rate))(input_layer)
encoder = layers.Dense(hidden_dim, activation="relu")(encoder)
decoder = layers.Dense(hidden_dim, activation="relu")(encoder)
decoder = layers.Dense(encoding_dim, activation="relu")(decoder)
decoder = layers.Dense(input_dim, activation="linear")(decoder)
autoencoder = tf.Keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoder)
autoencoder.summary()
```

[Error]

2021-09-29 23:12:15.331695: E tensorflow/core/lib/monitoring/collection_registry.cc:77] Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name: /tensorflow/api/keras/dropout/temp_rate_is_zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nprin\PycharmProjects\Work\test2.py", line 12, in 
from tensorflow.keras import layers
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\api_v2\keras_*init*_.py", line 10, in 
from keras import **version**
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras_*init*_.py", line 25, in 
from keras import models
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 20, in 
from keras import metrics as metrics_module
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics.py", line 26, in 
from keras import activations
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 20, in 
from keras.layers import advanced_activations
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers_*init*_.py", line 31, in 
from keras.layers.preprocessing.image_preprocessing import CenterCrop
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\image_preprocessing.py", line 24, in 
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_preprocessing
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing_*init*_.py", line 26, in 
from keras.utils import all_utils as utils
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\all_utils.py", line 34, in 
from keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 20, in 
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core_*init*_.py", line 20, in 
from keras.layers.core.dropout import Dropout
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core\dropout.py", line 26, in 
keras_temporary_dropout_rate = tf.**internal**.monitoring.BoolGauge(
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 360, in **init**
super(BoolGauge, self).**init**('BoolGauge', _bool_gauge_methods,
File "C:\Users\nprin.conda\envs\py64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\monitoring.py", line 135, in **init**
self._metric = self._metric_methods[self._label_length].create(*args)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: Another metric with the same name already exists.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Hi! I saw a typing error  in this line . autoencoder = tf.Keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoder) .  Sorted and Attaching edited code as Gist for reference.       https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/2683139271a386a3392e781bcb0c8ea1/stack_69378294.ipynb